# Magento 2 REST API -> PUT example (PHP)

Tags: php, magento, curl

I'm new to the Magento 2 REST API, but during the past day have been able to retrieve information using it to my backend system. GET -requests are easy enough, but I'm struggling with getting a correct PUT request together. What I need to do next is to update the order status from pending to processing, but just cannot figure out how to create a proper array to encode.

**Here's my code: *I need help with $data -part (4th line from top)***
(authentication part omitted - that works great)

```
$requestUrl='http://www.example.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]='.$increment_id; 
    $ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
    // Set status to processing
    $data = ((( need to change items[0] -> status from pending to processing  )));
    $data_json = json_encode($data);
    print '<br>JSON data: '.$data_json;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // Execute the query
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // Decode the result
    $result=  json_decode($result);
    print_r($result);
```

**Questions:**
1. How to formulate $data, so that it would be correct (items[0] -> status from pending to processing)
2. Is my PUT request correct otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you're using a wrong url for your PUT request. 
Correct url is

```
/V1/orders/create
```

In the `$data` field you have to put an array with the values you want to change in your order desired data. 
Something like:

```
"order" => [
     "status" => "processing"
]
```

Have a look to the list of possible api calls [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#!/salesOrderRepositoryV1/salesOrderRepositoryV1SavePut)